# C - Do-while followed by a switch with int cases. Validation is bad

Tags: c, validation, input, case, do-while

I'm trying to have a do-while before a switch so that I'm certain that the user input will match one of te cases. But I'm with 1 problems here.

If I give for example the input "5a" it will still use the 5 for execute case 5. How can I validate it so that the user can only give the exact numbers as input?

```
int move;
char validation[50];

do {
  printf("Input must be from 1 to 8:\n");
  fgets(validation, sizeof(validation), stdin);
  move = atoi(validation);
}
while (move < 1 || move > 8);

  switch (move) {
    case 1:
      dx = -1;
      dy = -1;
      break;
    case 2:
      dx = 0;
      dy = -1;
      break;
    case 3:
      dx = 1;
      dy = -1;
      break;
    case 4:
      dx = 1;
      dy = 0;
      break;
    case 5:
      dx = 1;
      dy = 1;
      break;
    case 6:
      dx = 0;
      dy = 1;
      break;
    case 7:
      dx = -1;
      dy = 1;
      break;
    case 8:
      dx = -1;
      dy = 0;
      break;
  }
```

Comment: At a glance, your `while` condition makes no sense, obviously `(move != 1) || (move != 2)` is always true.

Comment: guys Thank you for your comments! I now edited it but still have got the second problem!

Comment: While condition is still bad: should be `while (move < 1 || move > 8);` Better still, make it `while (! isValid(move))`, and let that function do all the extra validity checking you want.

Comment: `atoi()` will parse as much of the input string as it can; if you want to detect invalid inputs you should probably use `strtol()` and verify `endptr`points to the end of the string (easy to detect by checking `*endptr == '\0'`) when it's done.

Comment: Take [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390230/c-do-while-followed-by-a-switch-with-int-cases-validation-is-bad-and-program#comment83768563_48390230) very seriously. When the code says what it does explcitly, having bugs becomes very difficult, wheareas when the code is too complicated to read it and know immediately what it does, it will be a bug in itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can't detect `5` vs `5a` with atoi.  I suggest using [`strtol()`](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#strtol) instead

```
long int strtol (const char *str, char **endptr, int base);
```

Use the value `endPtr` to ensure your input is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The standard function `atoi`  declared like

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

actually represents a call of `strtol`

```
atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
```

However opposite to `strtol` it has no possibility to determine whether the input is correct.

So use `strtol` directly instead of `atoi`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int LOW_MOVE   = 1;
    const int UPPER_MOVE = 8;

    int move;
    char validation[50];


    int valid;
    do 
    {
        printf( "Input must be from %d to %d: ", LOW_MOVE, UPPER_MOVE );
        fgets( validation, sizeof( validation ), stdin );

        char *endptr;
        move = ( int )strtol( validation, &endptr, 10 );

        valid = endptr != validation;
        while ( valid && *endptr ) valid = isspace( ( unsigned char )*endptr++ );           
    } while ( !valid || move < LOW_MOVE || move > UPPER_MOVE );

    printf( "move = %d\n", move );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Input must be from 1 to 8: a
Input must be from 1 to 8: 5a
Input must be from 1 to 8: 5 a
Input must be from 1 to 8: 5 5
Input must be from 1 to 8: 5
move = 5
```

Comment: I just tried it with this and it works, problem is when when I enter too many wrong inputs, then I input the right one and It still asks for the right input :/

Comment: @RuiMartins I have not understood how you input data. But the program demonstrates different invalid inputs.

Comment: The problem is that if I enter the wrong input the program won't let me input the right.

Comment: The program just needs to accept 1 to 8, but if I enter for example 8H it will ask again for the input, and then I put 8 and it doesn't work.

But if I put 8 at first it works

Comment: @RuiMartins Did you try the demonstrative program? The program does not accept 8H. But it excepts 8 after the invalid input 8H. And the program output shows the logic.

Comment: @RuiMartins Run one more the demonstrative program and enter at first 8H and then after pressing the Enter key enter 8.

Answer (score -1):

You can ensure that the validation text only has digits in it. Here is some revised code. For the while loop, you can just check if its really out of range instead of doing individual matching for the 8 success cases.

```
int ensure_numeric(char *str) {

  while (str[0]) {
    if (str[0] >= '0' && str[0] <= '9') {
      str++;
      continue;
    }
    if (str[0] == '\r' || str[0] == '\n') {
      str++;
      continue;
    }
    break;
  }

  if (str[0]==0) return 0;

  return -1;

}

do {
  printf("Input must be from 1 to 8:\n");
  fgets(validation, sizeof(validation), stdin);
  move = atoi(validation);
  if (ensure_numeric(validation)) {
    printf("You did not enter all digits only.\n");
    move = 0;
  }
 }
 while (move < 1 || move > 8);
```

Comment: Just use [strtol()](https://www-s.acm.illinois.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.13.html#strtol) like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48390406/1983495) suggested.